# Python gzip.open .tell() has a linear increasing factor making it slow

Tags: python, file-io, gzip

Using Python 3.3.5, I have a code that looks like:

```
with gzip.open(fname, mode='rb') as fh:
    fh.seek(savedPos)
    for line in fh:
        # some work is done
        savedPos = fh.tell()
```

The work being done on each row is already quite taxing on the system, So I wasn't hoping for great numbers. But I threw in a debug counter and got the following result:

```
48 rows/sec
28 rows/sec
19 rows/sec
15 rows/sec
13 rows/sec
13 rows/sec
9 rows/sec
10 rows/sec
9 rows/sec
9 rows/sec
8 rows/sec
8 rows/sec
8 rows/sec
8 rows/sec
7 rows/sec
7 rows/sec
7 rows/sec
7 rows/sec
5 rows/sec
...
```

Which tells me something was off, so I put the `fh.tell()` in the debug-counter/timer function, making so that `fh.tell()` only executed once a second and got a stable **65 rows/sec**.

Am I completely off the shelf or shouldn't fh.tell() be extremely quick? or is this a side-affect of gzip alone?

I used to store the file-position manually but it bugged out occasionally due to different file-endings, encoding issues etc so I figured `fh.tell()` would be more accurate.

Are there alternatives or can you speed up fh.tell() some how?

Answer (score 3):

My experience with zlib (albeit using it from C rather than python, but I suspect the issue is the same) is that seeking is what is slow. zlib doesn't keep track of where in the file it is, so if you seek it has to uncompress from the beginning in order to count how many uncompressed bytes forward it should seek to.

In other words, reading or writing sequentially is fine. If you have to seek, you're in for a world of hurt.

Comment: That would for sure explain the behavior I'm experiencing. If that's the case my only two options would be to either try to keep track of the file-position myself or sacrifice accuracy for performance.

Answer (score 3):

I rather doubt that you can expect `fh.seek(...)` to perform well.

gzip uses a compression algorithm where the way things are compressed depends on the entire history of the data that preceded it. So have an efficient `seek` operation you would also have to restore the internal state of the decoder.

In any case, here is the code for the `seek` method: ([lines 435-442](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/gzip.py#l435))

```
   elif self.mode == READ:
        if offset < self.offset:
            # for negative seek, rewind and do positive seek
            self.rewind()
        count = offset - self.offset
        for i in xrange(count // 1024):
            self.read(1024)
        self.read(count % 1024)
```

So seeking is performed by just performing `read` calls - i.e. reading and decompressing the data until it's at the correct file position, and if you seek backwards it just rewinds and reads forward from the start of the file.

Comment: Thank you for that research, saved me some time looking through the source. Shouldn't be to hard patching the zlib all together.